# Promise and $q in angular

Tags: angular

I have the following code. I'm looking for the the module for promise and $q in Angular 5 but did not find any useful detailed info. The code below is in AngularJS and Javascript.

I want to have to transfer this code to Angular 5 and TypeScript.
This is a mock service to mock the data:

```
angular.module('reports.appActivity').factory('AppActiveMockServices', ['$q',
    function ($q) {    
      var appActivity;

      function loadappActivity(params) {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
          cancel = function (reason) {
            deferred.resolve(reason);
          };
        injectappActivity(params);

        deferred.resolve(appActivity);
        return {
          promise: deferred.promise,
          cancel: cancel
        };
      }

      function injectappActivity(params) {
        var total = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)),
          someUsage = total - Math.floor((Math.random() * 80)),
          tempValue,
          maxIndex = 0,
          deltaTime=0,
          daysSelected,
          timeBegin,
          timeEnd,
          d = new Date(),
          dayInmilliseconds;

        appActivity = {total: total, items: []};

        deltaTime = 24 * 3600 * 1000; // daily

        timeBegin = (params.timestamp_start).getTime();
        timeEnd =(params.timestamp_end).getTime();
        daysSelected =  Math.round((timeEnd - timeBegin) / 3600/24/1000);

        if (daysSelected <= 1 ) {
          maxIndex = 24 ; // one day , resolution is hourly data
          deltaTime = 3600 * 1000; // hourly
          dayInmilliseconds = (d.getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000));
        }
        else if (daysSelected <=  7)  {
          maxIndex = 7; // 7 days , resolution is daily data
          dayInmilliseconds = (d.getTime() - (7* 24 * 3600 * 1000));
        }
        else if (daysSelected <= 30) {
          maxIndex = 30; // 30 days , resolution is daily data
          dayInmilliseconds = (d.getTime() - (30* 24 * 3600 * 1000));
        }
        else { // custom range
          maxIndex = daysSelected; // x days , resolution is daily data
          dayInmilliseconds = (d.getTime() - (daysSelected * 24 * 3600 * 1000));
        }

        for (var index = 0; index < maxIndex; index++) {
          d.setTime(dayInmilliseconds + (index * deltaTime));
          total = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100));
          tempValue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50));
          someUsage = (tempValue > total) ? total : (total - tempValue);

          var item = {
            'total': total,
            'some_usage': someUsage,
            'date': d.toISOString().slice(0, 19) + 'Z'
          };
          appActivity.items.push(item);
        }
      }

      return {
        loadappActivity: loadappActivity
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question cannot get a quality answer in current state. It's unclear how this service is supposed to be used, what you expect from the answer and what's your level of expertise with Angular. As a rule of thumb, observables are supposed to be used in Angular. They are more universal than promises, and they are cancellable - while promises aren't. So the service should likely be rewritten to observables - so should other units that consume it.

Answer (score 1):

> looking ... for promise and $q in Angular 5 but not find a useful detail info

In Angular, assuming you left the polyfills.ts alone, you should be able to just use `Promise` like in my example below

> Want to ... transfer this code to using Angular 5 and Typescript.

Here's the basic setup to get you going, i'm not going to copy all of that code over because i see a few things missing/weird in it that might have greater implications to fixing (like for instance you have a params arg that is never used and also a function `injectappActivity` which is never defined)

consider using the angular cli to generate a service

```
ng generate service app-active-mock
```

and then updating it like so

```js
# app-active-mock.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class AppActiveMockService {
  public loadappActivity(): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.resolve(...)
  }
}
```

Also a bit unrelated, but you're likely not coming up with any useful searches for things related to Promises in Angular because for the most part, the community has embraced Observables

Comment: Thank you for response to my question. Actually this is service to mock the data. Updated the code with the missing function

Comment: @Kim2018 I think this answers your question pretty well. What other information are you looking for?